# Analog NOT gate

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, not-gate

I am pretty new to electronics and was wondering how you could get a NOT gate for a 9v battery. I understand that it can not make power at the output when there is no power input, so it would probably require multiple inputs. I was basically thinking something like this: 
Two inputs, A and B
One output, C

Input A is always on to give power, and output C Is the opposite of input B.

It seems simple, I just have no idea what this is called, or where you can buy it, do you guys have any ideas?

Edit: Basically I want to connect input A and B from a 9V battery to a device, and I want output C to be the opposite of B, meaning that if I cut the wire between the battery and input B, the output will turn on, getting it's  power from input A which is still connected.

Opposite as in on will be off

I do not know much about electronics, so sorry if it is not very specific. Just tell me if you want more clarification.

Comment: What is the "opposite"? Can you give an example? Are you talking about inverting amplifier?

Comment: I think it would help if you described what you're trying to do with the 9V and why you are looking for a NOT operation on it (a NOT gate only has one input). If you're new to electronics then someone on here can probably provide a much better solution over what you're trying to do with a NOT gate.

Comment: Sorry, updated it now.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you have two devices X and Y.  Normally you want X to be powered and Y to be unpowered, but if you cut one of the wires to X then Y will become powered.  Is that right?  And why cut a wire when you could use a switch? What is your application?

Comment: That is pretty accurate, Justin. I figured I had to use an inverted relay switch, thanks to your help.

Answer (score 2):

A [CD4001B](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4001BC,11BC.pdf) with both inputs connected together will act as a NOT gate.  Each package contains 4 NOR gates. It will operate from a 9V battery with no other components- the + goes to pin 14 and the - to pin 7.

[image]

You could also ground the unused inputs (say pins 5,6, 8, 9 , 12, 13) and leave the unused inputs 4, 10,11 open. The input (1,2) should be near 0V for a '0' and near Vcc for a '1', and the output (pin 3) will be the opposite. It can drive a light load such as a few mA for an indicator LED but not something like a motor.

Such a quad gate in singles should be less than 50 cents. Each gate has about 10 transistors internally, so about 40 altogether.

Answer (score 0):

A "gate" doesn't usually supply power, but just a small amount of current to drive other gates' inputs.  How much current do you need the output to supply? It sounds like you are looking for a relay or P-channel MOSFET instead of a logic gate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BenceKaulics - My interpretation of the question was that he wants to "make power at the output" when another voltage is low and "[has] no idea what this is called", and my answer is "a P-channel MOSFET instead of a logic gate". My interpretation may be wrong, though.

Comment: You just suggest to use a MOSFET or relay, but do not explain how these parts will act as a NOT gate. And also you ask for more information, so all in all it seemed to me more like a comment. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an XOR logic gate.
If your input A will always be powered ON, our input B will be inverted in the output. (There is only one output)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please note that OP is asking for an _analog_ gate. Also, this question is over three years old.